# Improving speed on loading css

Tags: css

I'm wondering is there a difference in performance by the browser if you code like this:

```
<div class="css-1 css-2 css-3 css-4 css-5">

<div class="css-everything">
```

Loads the site faster if you put everything in .css-everything, instead of partial css classes?

Comment: i don't think it's faster. i will be faster and better to put css code in different css files. this will keep it clean and you can search faster when you need to change something.

Comment: @KeesSonnema Only when in development. When you actually deploy the site you'll want to concatenate all the files together to reduce the number of HTTP requests.

Comment: @Kees Sonnema: Yi Jiang is right – it's all about saving HTTP requests. You can also minify the CSS-files to use even less bandwidth. But I don't really understood the question. CSS-Classes don't have anything to with where they are defined.

Comment: Any difference is negligible unless your page is very complex. Don't base this decision on performance concerns. There are a hundred other more important things to optimize first.

Answer (score 1):

Its only matter of *perspective* for the conditions as you stated. Nothing Else.

> **Examples**:

Consider you have a scenarios like:

**Scene:1**

CSS:

```
.button {
    width:100px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
.blueBG {
    background-color: blue;
}
.redBG {
    background-color: red;
}
.left{
    float: left;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
.right {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<a href="stackoverflow.com" class="button red left">StackOverflow</a>
<p class="blue">Text with blue background</p>
<img class="left" src="image.jpg"></img>
```

NOW THINK, if I use a code here somewhat like this:

CSS:

```
.blueButtonLeft {
    width:100px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: blue;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
.blueButtonRight {
    width:100px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: blue;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 10px;
 }
 .redButtonLeft {
    width:100px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: red;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
.redButtonRight {
    width:100px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: red;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 10px;
 }
```

HTML:

```
<a href="stackoverflow.com" class="blueButtonLeft">StackOverflow</a>
<!-- Need of defferent code for img and p -->
```

> I hope the difference is clear. Isn't it?

**Scene:2**

I am sorry I need to go off for sometime will surely back and edit it more later.